# Angular2 ExceptionHandler - check if error object is Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am currently using the following code to handle exceptions:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    console.warn(error);
}
```

The code works fine, I can see the error in the console.  The error is a Response object, defined in @angular/core. However, the error parameter is 'any'.  I can't change the error type (e.g. error:Response), because it wont necessarily be a Response object, it could be anything.

I wanted to use (error instanceof Response), but that wont work, because error is a type of object, which makes sense.

**UPDATE**

So it turns out `(error instanceof Response)` does work after all.  For some reason it doesn't appear to work when you're debugging the typescript using VS Code.  I put a watch on it and it always returned false.  Maybe it's because i'm not checking at run-time

Anyway, important thing is that in the context of Angular2 Response objects, `instanceof` will work just fine as they do have a constructor

Thank to @DanSimon for helping to narrow down what was going wrong, and for providing other ways to check the type of an object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Since TypeScript is really just compiling down to JS, classes don't really exist. I can think of two ways you could check, you can use a "User-Defined Type Guard" or use the "instanceof type guard". The User-Defined Type Guard is just a fancy way of checking a property/function of the object to determine its Type, the advantage is TS won't complain about a "missing property/function". Using the "instanceof" works but only if the Object has a constructor as it's comparing the two Object's constructors. So if your Object doesn't have a constructor it's a no go. You can find the documentation for these two [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

I also made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/72L5XBNgNE4qKX1RjvT1?p=preview) demonstrating how they work. The results will load into the console, so use your browsers debug tool to see the results. All the work is being done on "app/child.component.ts" in the "ngOnChanges" function.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
  console.log();
  console.log("Custom function isSimpleChange:", this.isSimpleChange(changes));
  console.log("Using instanceof SimpleChange:", (changes instanceof SimpleChange));
  console.log("Using Object.prototype.toString.call():", Object.prototype.toString.call(changes));
  console.log("Logging the object itself:",changes);
  console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  let testExample = new ExampleObject();
  console.log("Custom function isExampleObject:", this.isExampleObject(testExample));
  console.log("Using instanceof ExampleObject:", (testExample instanceof ExampleObject));
  console.log("Using Object.prototype.toString.call():" + Object.prototype.toString.call(testExample));
  console.log(testExample);


  this._result = changes.value.currentValue;
  this._changes++;
}
```

You will probably need to leverage both and also "typeof" for your primitive types to do a complete inspection of the object. So using "typeof" to check for basic types "string","number","boolean". Then using "instanceof" to see if the constructors match, finally using a "User-Defined Type Guard" to look for specific "properties/functions".